# Selinux php-fpm httpd and mariadb socket connection

Tags: security, selinux, socket, mariadb, phpmyadmin

*New note with important details*

I just ran a few version tests and resulted in the following:
Alright, here’s my latest update:

- 10.5 works
- 10.6 doesn’t
- 10.7 works
- 10.8 work
- etc.

I was hoping to use 10.6 since it is the LTS release…clearly there is something wrong with it though. I’m on the MariaDB slack channel at the moment, but for now I’ll revert to 10.5 from the MariaDB repo, since that has support for 2 years-ish. Am I missing something else? I didn't change anything but the MariaDB version and restarting the process.

*Edit note for reference*

Installing the EL Repo MariaDB 10.5 installs a package "mysql-selinux" and the default repo (epel-release?) allows the necessary communications and php-fpm can connect to mariadb fine. It seems like maybe the MariaDB repo package is missing this functionality. I would have installed the EL repo MariaDB on my AL 8.6 system, but removed it and went with the MariaDB repo for regular operation.
I found the source for "mysql-selinux" here and it's not trivial like my "fix":

https://github.com/devexp-db/mysql-selinux/blob/master/mysql.te

this package is NOT installed on my 8.6 system which works...

---

I have a system running fine with SELinux enabled on AlmaLinux 8.6. I'm using stock AL 8.6 Apache/httpd (2.4.37 I think) and php from Remi's Repo:

https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/

I initially installed MariaDB 10.4 directly from the MariaDB repo using these instructions:

https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-install-mariadb-on-rhel8-centos8/

SELinux is enabled and I don't believe I made any customizations specifically for php-fpm to connect to the mysql.sock socket/process. I recently upgraded to MariaDB 10.6, again from the MariaDB repo, and everything continued working as it always did. For reference my "working" validation is using phpMyAdmin configured to connect through a local socket.

I've installed my AlmaLinux 9 VM with stock Apache/httpd (2.4.51 I think). I installed MariaDB  10.6 from the same repo with the same instructions. Now, I'm getting a denial from SELinux for php-fpm (running as httpd_t) trying to connect to the /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock process (running as unconfinsed_service_t). This denial prevents the connection and subsequent login from phpMyAdmin (running under the php-fpm service):

```
time->Mon Sep 26 22:14:07 2022
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1664244847.002:83): proctitle=7068702D66706D3A20706F6F6C20777777
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1664244847.002:83): arch=c000003e syscall=42 success=no exit=-13 a0=5 a1=7ffc156c46b0 a2=1b a3=557032b785a0 items=0 ppid=706 pid=738 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="php-fpm" exe="/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/sbin/php-fpm" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1664244847.002:83): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=738 comm="php-fpm" path="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
```

This ONLY shows up on my AL 9 install, AL 8.6 does not report this denial and allows the connection and subsequent login. I checked the file and process SELinux contexts and they are the same between 8.6 and 9. I've also tried different php-fpm versions, including the same between my 8.6 install and 9 (both php 7.4 from Remi). I've tried running the fpm pool under apache:apache and under my phpMyAdmin user with group apache.

Any advice on how to track this down? I can "fix" the SELinux denial with the following policy, but it allows httpd to connect to any unconfined process:

```
module phpfpm_mariadb_socket 1.0;

require {
        type httpd_t;
        type unconfined_service_t;
        class unix_stream_socket connectto;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t unconfined_service_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

I see two obvious differences: Apache 2.4.37 vs 2.4.51 (and potential related SELinux policy changes which I couldn't track down) and EL 8.6 vs EL 9 SELinux core changes (both had "latest" available updates applied). I copied the phpMyAdmin install from my 8.6 system into my 9 system, under the same usernames with the same permissions. I don't think that the php-fpm user:group configuration is relevant to the process contexts, or is it?

Comment: check "getsebool -a | grep httpd"

Comment: @RemiCollet yes I checked those, and have the following enabled. BUT the same booleans work for 10.5 that aren't working for 10.6
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1 -P
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1 -P I've been looking for other bools that might be different between those installs, but I haven't been very effective.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this happens with MariaDB 10.6 on AlmaLinux 9 and that the SELinux policy posted by @Brian works.

Comment: I was hesitant to use that policy as it means httpd could connect to ANY unconfined service. I was hoping for something a little more direct, but maybe I'm being obsessive.